# ¿Cómo encontrar las coordenadas de los píxeles negros de un objeto?

Tags: c++

Mi duda es cómo puedo encontrar las coordenadas X y Y de todos los píxeles negros del objeto de la imagen.

Esta es la imagen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz7ew.png (*la figura negra tiene un grosor de 1 pixel*)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo contar el total de pixeles negros y encontar las coordenas X y Y del centro de la figura negra con este codigo:

```
int c = 0;
double x = 0, y = 0;
for(i=0; i<high; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<width; j++)
    {
        if(Img->imx[i*width+j]==0)
        {
             c=c+1;  //conteo de pixeles negros
             x=x+j;
             y=y+i;
        }
    }
}
if(c>0)
{
    x=x/c; //centro en X
    y=y/c;  //centro en Y
}
```

Pero necesito encontrar las coordenadas X y Y de cada pixel negro.

Comment: por un lado, ya tienes las coordenadas de todos los pixeles negros en el mismo ciclo donde los cuentas, X y Y son aquellas coordenadas. aunque si quieres optimizar el codigo, al momento de encontrar el primer pixel negro, puedes aplicar el algoritmo floodfill, pero sin la parte de pintar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: ¿`i`y `j` no son las coordenadas x e y? De ser así, cuando dices que "cuentas los píxeles negros" ya tienes las coordenadas de cada pixel negro. Almacena dichas coordenadas en un vector o donde necesites y listo.

Answer (score 2):

Se que esta no es la mejor respuesta ya que no pondré código pero te  va a servir. Existe OpenCV para hacer estas tareas, es mucho mas eficiente que hacerlo en forma manual Te dejo un link para que lo veas en C++ (Yo hago esto en Python).

El link es [este](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html), y tenés que buscar Accessing image elements.